# PHP Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: metabox, callbacks

Confused. Writing a plugin with which I have other callbacks working similarly fine. But when adding a meta box its failing on the callback with error:

> PHP Warning:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object

Fairly standard error but I can't work out why im receiving it. I have the following (stripped down) in a class.

```
function __construct(){     
   add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'init' ) );
}

function init() {
   add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box('model', 'Parent', array(&$this,'parent_meta_box'), 'model', 'side', 'high');});
}

function parent_meta_box( $post ) {
   // whatever happens here...
}
```

As far as I am aware I am doing the callback correctly with &this but nothing renders inside the metabox though it appears and I receive the above standard PHP error. Ive stripped it right back in my code down to this and its creating the meta box just won't put anything inside it. I have put debug logging in and it doesnt reach it but gets before and after. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this` is not defined in the scope of a closure. Change it to:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() use ($this) { 
add_meta_box('model', 'Parent', array($this,'parent_meta_box'), 'model', 'side', 'high');
});
```

Or better separate both and create a real method instead of a closure.

Comment: I'll never understand the aversion to declaring proper callbacks.

Comment: Thanks so much made sense instantly one of those d'oh moments. I usually create real methods don't know what I decided not to this time. I should have just fallen back to previous practices. Thank you!

Comment: @Jimbo Note that I have removed the `&` from `&$this`. Object are always passed by reference in PHP 5. `&$this` is PHP 4.

Comment: @toscho much appreciated! Already updated ;)